# Consulta SQL para ver usuario con mas solicitudes de amistad confirmadas

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

En un ejercicio de Base de Datos me dan una BD con la cual debo de tomar 2 tablas `TBL_AMIGOS` y `TBL_ESTATUS_SOLICITUDES` para hacer una consulta para saber el usuario con mayor cantidad de solicitudes confirmadas.

He intentado con `HAVING` y `COUNT` pero lo estoy utilizando mal.

**`TBL_AMIGOS`**

- `CODIGO_USUARIO`
- `CODIGO_AMIGO`
- `CODIGO_ESTATUS`
- `CODIGO_TIPO_RELACIO`

**`TBL_ESTATUS_SOLICITUDES`**

- `CODIGO_ESTATUS`
- `NOMBRE_ESTATUS`

Las tablas a usar están en la esquina superior izquierda del modelo relacional.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que una amistad este confirmada en el registro de `TBL_AMISTADES` el `CODIGO_ESTATUS` debe ser igual a `1` que significa `CONFIRMADA` como se ve en la imagen. En si lo que necesito es saber que USUARIO tiene la mayor cantidad de `1` en el campo `CODIGO_ESTATUS`.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Anthony. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrás definir con tus palabras cómo se define en la base de datos una solicitud de amistad? ¿No te parecería más gráfico incluir 3 o 4 filas de datos? Y quizás sea más práctico para alguien que quiera ayudarte mostrar algunas de las sentencias que intentaste, por más que no funcionen.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo e hecho.

Comment: ¿Todas las solicitudes son de amistad, o también hay otro tipo de solicitudes que debieras obtener de la tabla TBL_TIPOS_RELACIONES? En mi opinión, siguen faltando datos para poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: Lo único que necesito es solamente saber cual es el usuario con mas amigos, lo demás es irrelevante. Este es exactamente el enunciado que me tengo que resolver "Mostrar el usuario con mayor cantidad de amigos confirmados (El más cool).".

Comment: ¿Qué significa que tenga un `CODIGO_TIPO_RELACION = 3`? ¿Eso también es una solicitud de amistad?

Comment: 1 Amig@
2 Novi@
3 Espos@
4 Herman@
5 Sobrin@
6 Ti@
7 Prim@

Comment: El CODIGO_TIPO_RELACION no son solicitudes de amistad, lo que necesito saber en si es que usuario tiene el mayor numero de registros con el CODIGO_ESTATUS = 1, ya que el 1 en el CODIGO_ESTATUS = Confirmada, osea que ya se confirmo su solicitud de amistad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera sencilla de lograrlo es ordenando los resultados por numero de registros con el `CODIGO_ESTATUS = 1` (o `NOMBRE_ESTATUS = 'CONFIRMADA'`), y luego usando `where rownum < 2` para limitar el query al primer resultado.

```
select codigo_usuario
  from (select a.codigo_usuario
          from tbl_amigos a
          join tbl_estatus_solicitudes e
            on e.codigo_estatus = a.codigo_estatus
           and e.nombre_estatus = 'CONFIRMADA'
         group by a.codigo_usuario
         order by count(*) desc)
 where rownum < 2
```

Y para mostrar el usuario con menos amigos seria simplemente cambiando el "desc" por "asc", así:

```
select codigo_usuario
  from (select a.codigo_usuario
          from tbl_amigos a
          join tbl_estatus_solicitudes e
            on e.codigo_estatus = a.codigo_estatus
           and e.nombre_estatus = 'CONFIRMADA'
         group by a.codigo_usuario
         order by count(*) asc)
 where rownum < 2
```

Comment: Gracias **SSTAN** , si a funcionad. Y muchas gracias a todos lo que aportaron.

Comment: Si la respuesta  resolvió sus problemas. Marcar como aceptada. Gracias